# How to delete CONSTRAINT refernase on two tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have the two following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  created timestamp DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blog_users (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  referance_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  created timestamp DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Im using this to reference the two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE blog_users
ADD CONSTRAINT blog_users 
FOREIGN KEY (referance_id) REFERENCES blog (id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If i want to remove the reference between the two tables, is there some command that can undo the last ALTER table command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ([DOC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE blog_users DROP FOREIGN KEY blog_users;
```

There is no way to undo the last executed query;

Comment: Ok, so what does this ALTER TABLE do? throws me a error.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT id' at line 1

Comment: DROP CONSTRAINT only works for Oracle and SQL Server, use DROP FOREIGN KEY with Mysql